# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many create/insert does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models -

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :surveys, join_table: 'employee_surveys'
end


class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees, join_table: 'employee_surveys'
end
```

When I do `Employee.first.surveys.create(name: "New Survey")` it generates an error complaining that `employee_id` is `null` ??

Comment: What's the exact error/backtrace?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use an instance of the employee class here, not the class itself.

Like:

```
employee = Employee.first
employee.surveys.create(name: "New Survey")
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I am doing a ".first"

Comment: In that case, it would probably be helpful to see the actual error. Maybe double check that the employee_surveys table exists with a employee_id column. btw, typically you'd want to follow the naming convention and name your join table 'employees_surveys', and then you wouldn't need to specify it as a param.

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "employee_id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: and yes "employee_surveys" does have the column - employee_id